# Set boolean field to true if query match otherwise set to false

Tags: postgresql

I have bunch of ids `someIds` (20 - 100 thousands) and table with more than 12 millions rows like that:

```
spaceShips(
    id BIGINT,
    shipType TEXT,
    shipName TEXT,
    hasArtificialIntelligence boolean
)
```

And I need for all rows where `shipType='warship'` (about 2 millions) set field `hasArtificialIntelligence` true if `spaceShips.id` in `someIds` otherwise set false. Is there a better way than two update queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, one update is sufficient:

```
UPDATE spaceShips
    SET hasArtificialIntelligence = spaceShips.id in ( ...,someIds,... )
WHERE shipType='warship'
```

spaceShips.id in ( ...,someIds,... ) will evaluate to either true or false (assuming someid is not null)

Comment: And which variant should I prefer with given numbers? It seems like two queries will touch less records. (I forget to mention that hasArtificialIntelligence most likely already set to false) `UPDATE spaceShips SET hasArtificialIntelligence = TRUE WHERE id IN someIds AND shipType='warship'` and `UPDATE spceShips SET hasArtificialIntelligence = FALSE WHERE id NOT IN someIds AND hasArtificialIntelligence = TRUE AND shipType='warship'`

Comment: When I said "touch" I meant "will change". Because of additional condition in second query `hasArtificilaIntelligence = TRUE`. One query will change all records with `shipType='warship'`

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up with this solution:

Partial index on hasArtificialIntelligence

```
CREATE INDEX hasArtificialIntelligenceIDX ON spaceShips(id) WHERE hasArtificialIntelligence IS TRUE;
```

And update with two queries

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE hasIntelligenceIds(id BIGINT);  --temp table because I have
COPY hasIntelligenceIds(id) FROM 'ids.csv';       --too many ids to pass as parameters

UPDATE spaceShips SET hasArtificialIntelligence = TRUE WHERE id IN someIds AND shipType='warship';
UPDATE spceShips SET hasArtificialIntelligence = FALSE WHERE id NOT IN someIds AND hasArtificialIntelligence = TRUE AND shipType='warship';
```